# MVC3 Controller not receiving any parameter values

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Using JQuery, I am passing values to an action in the controller. customerId and productId are not null:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "Customer/Product/",
                data: { Customer: customerID, Product: productId},
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    // you may need to handle me if the json is invalid
                    // this is the ajax object
                },
                success: function (json) {
                    $("#productName").innerHTML = json;
                    alert(json);
                    alert($("#startDate").innerHTML);
                }
            });
```

In MVC3 controller, i have the action:

```
public ActionResult Product(string Customer, string Product)
{
//both are null
}
```

I don't know why both are null? Please guide

Comment: Did you verify your request in Fiddler or Firebug?

Comment: Does the Framework function off of query string values and the server run a MOD rewrite?
(I'm unfamiliar with MVC3)

Answer (score 1):

MVC may be expecting a JSON string.  Try using this as your data

```
data: JSON.stringify({ Customer: customerID, Product: productId})
```

Comment: just as an added note - the integers shouldn't break the controller as they would be serialized/sent over as strings anyways.

Comment: @AdamT - I would have been surprised if it did.  So, looking at your answer, can you not pass JSON data to a controller action via GET?

Comment: to clarify slightly-       data:JSON.stringify({ Customer: customerID, Product: productId})   (no semicolon, this is the complete line)

Comment: you can send (just by default you can't return json on a get method for security reasons)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "Customer/Product/",
                data:  "Customer="+customerID +"&Product="+productId,
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    // you may need to handle me if the json is invalid
                    // this is the ajax object
                },
                success: function (json) {
                    $("#productName").innerHTML = json;
                    alert(json);
                    alert($("#startDate").innerHTML);
                }
            });
```

Try this way.

Comment: its not necessary to include like that, is can also open you up to XSS attacks.

Comment: Can i see your ActionResult Method that you call via ajax ?

Answer (score 1):

If you change it to a "POST" request it should work.

However it looks like you are actually trying to just "GET" data from the server which should really be encoded in your URL e.g. mysite.com/Customer/{customer_id}/Product/{product_id}.  In this case you'll probably need to change your routing rules.

Answer (score 1):

I just did "File -> New Project" and just added the one controller and tried directly using:

```
var customerID = 42;
var productId = 4242;
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:51622/Customer/Product",
        data: { Customer: customerID, Product: productId},
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            // you may need to handle me if the json is invalid
            // this is the ajax object
        },
        success: function (json) {
            console.log(json);
        }
    });
```

It binds the values just fine, so you might want to grab [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or something similiar and make sure that you are actually sending values to the server.

Comment: The action link is @Html.ActionLink("Product", "Product", "Combined", null, new { id = "selectedProduct" }) and the javascript function is bound to its onclick. can you see any problems with it?

Comment: In the code you posted you have the url "Customer/Product/" but your controller is called "Combined" so I'm guessing you have some custom routing to make that work. Could you post the code to that?